# Display the file's name without its root in Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have two questions about Shell Script. I'm doing a simple script to display a list of files greater than a number that is passed as argument.

```
find $1 -size +$2c -exec ls -lh {} \;| awk '{print $9 -> $5}'
```

where `$1` is the root, `$2` is the size, `$9` and `$5` are the name of the file and its size respectively.

First question: Is there a way to display the file's name without its root? I just want the name of the file.
Second question: Is there a way, in case I don't specify the root, the shell script takes the actual root?

Comment: Did you try `info basename`?

Comment: Probably not because he probably doesn't know about `basename`.

Comment: Hello! basename seems do not work inside the print of awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell `ls` to only print the basename of the file.  However, you can use the `-printf` action of `find` to print the size and basename:

```
find $1 -size +$2c -printf "%f -> %s\n"
```

If you want the sizes in a human-readable format, one way would be to only use `find` to locate your desired files and then print the basename and size for each result:

```
find $1 -size +$2c | while read file; do echo $(basename "$file") "->" $(ls -lh "$file" | awk '{print $5}') ; done
```

EDIT:

Printing a total at the end means building a total within the loop:

```
#! /bin/bash
total=0
while read file; do
    total=$(($total+$(ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}')))
    echo $(basename "$file") "->" $(ls -lh "$file" | awk '{print $5}')
done < <(find $1 -size +$2c)
echo $total
```

Comment: Hi! Your approach works very fine! But, how can I store the value of the $5 (the file's size) and prints the total at the and of the loop.

Comment: initialize a counter to 0 and add the size to the counter each loop iteration.  i've updated my answer with an example of such.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the `basename` command.

```
$ basename /foo/bar/bat/baz/whatever.txt
whatever.txt
```